# How to get this css design

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this `css` design as shown below  :

[image: date]

But my output looks like :

[image: op]

You see date field on the top right corner in image. Red color was image.

I have set that red as background to `<p>` tag have class `.img-datpick`.

My question was

> How to place text within that red background as like in image?
>
> How to Move that to top right corner?

Thanks in advance.

```css
.articles {
  margin-top: 3%;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}

.articles .articles-img .img-datpick {
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OFHJ7eqWeBF8yamaHpADLWySPh6a9tlsSUFGCV3TBgrmh4wfRGr2IQbw03KusmRisX1knyGNPtHKpEGav48S694cRljgkNR80PpHX8ruLhstR1ayzXlDs9vNzyvQeqQtHcfMc7VqA9O3jlfjynaCvKJCGSS0v-L0vZcz0Ah-w8t3JZXAfU-Qk8O8zcmsgWvbr7qkhtP3BuXZy71sKMCXzIpF-DKaaVQb7FYAAtguTefF54IsHmNU4wOleOcfCjJhoDjOeGQEv6DUcLnQuh_sHx1sL4x9PkskTEIadc_VRlKECtpa-72JFGVBhoCx8OBoMRM037HlOdEy4qGqN1ZdiGB5z1zGjsBfa-qcz6-JP5KjZiTuKD3GlWJAhnXnFeimaJsjaTCTzi664Hc4Hc-dlxDzIO9pgs4RqaUqWtbl7bJtdkRHEDaOpDZLLZsNJj-2ijuHg7ie8TLS_U6YrE_B7MJMEeFR112dPg-ijQrG-8qmZKb69m4zPj_gEqj1PXPqsv3m9s2C-6DxzH0TuB7mEWzH_F11tK2PKe0O7kCR5dFVekgvtuxLq_VRISwz5kh8MtfFf2ONaV5qNJ_5ibFEby-3pEe7NTbAwCaQtTwx7CQK8A=w62-h65-no);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 65px;
}

.articles .documentation-content {
  background: #edebec;
  padding: 5px 8px 8px 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p {
  color: #848589;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p i {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-h1 {
  color: #848589;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-p {
  color: #848589;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-p span {
  color: #de0000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 articles">
  <div class="articles-img">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_26gdiWJg5Nem0LcB3j91bZOLoFgUdqM-1HtbmJfwmUIKY_bQoJd5Yali_l5efltYySgX87gobteQ-6Es2Djns1GM3RA355O4ziUwwE5ceS5eZojE5CUQexdT2gRUzKf672ul9Yic6PDm6bGVZircbss_Y6O6Uc3s8oRnu2cMYV63CDcUlKRwIoLHedRBtEVm8dqQqKGIBqz0JtrNCkFBcNNXPGwhhpWQFzn27HlaDtRc0l5Tp6C8FOzornDIlbjZeqBA3YRYN7-5xPDh9YK0sJPrQN_BWOF5dzrOgUmmuFJKZAzcK2OzyQ0kG0qIPaciOQFkiWR3VXL2HTFSv7MbTqCjtwKbkplLtoEnl6oGZKNcjEIRHQKjM_Km0JQ-YZv8OopV-iCPTM0vlgl4bPz5iaIvbRlZmwFndWR_jHCBcbPlcRPXMowsokVFrrlP24sGSQBSRzK4rlDgTOn1wKbPwWrO7dKKdUOuPxqKHOAN_k-mLk9gAQkw3Hy5crX-OcNUvgNjYUjlazX2Oo56gy7NKbwWkfEWEgi4MB83fqOhi1SwG3TjkL0PqyAnhDQi5gAEMMFO2CKj3AaNHP2KepoFRgMjd5JmsMOfdJT6iDFNtwAQQ=w385-h214-no">

    <p class="img-datpick">28<span>june</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="documentation-content">
    <div class="doc-posted">
      <p><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> posted by: john doe</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 28 june 2015</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 36 comments</p>
    </div>

    <h1 class="doc-h1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <p class="doc-p">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam , quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span>read more..</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.articles {
  margin-top: 3%;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}

.articles .articles-img .img-datpick {
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OFHJ7eqWeBF8yamaHpADLWySPh6a9tlsSUFGCV3TBgrmh4wfRGr2IQbw03KusmRisX1knyGNPtHKpEGav48S694cRljgkNR80PpHX8ruLhstR1ayzXlDs9vNzyvQeqQtHcfMc7VqA9O3jlfjynaCvKJCGSS0v-L0vZcz0Ah-w8t3JZXAfU-Qk8O8zcmsgWvbr7qkhtP3BuXZy71sKMCXzIpF-DKaaVQb7FYAAtguTefF54IsHmNU4wOleOcfCjJhoDjOeGQEv6DUcLnQuh_sHx1sL4x9PkskTEIadc_VRlKECtpa-72JFGVBhoCx8OBoMRM037HlOdEy4qGqN1ZdiGB5z1zGjsBfa-qcz6-JP5KjZiTuKD3GlWJAhnXnFeimaJsjaTCTzi664Hc4Hc-dlxDzIO9pgs4RqaUqWtbl7bJtdkRHEDaOpDZLLZsNJj-2ijuHg7ie8TLS_U6YrE_B7MJMEeFR112dPg-ijQrG-8qmZKb69m4zPj_gEqj1PXPqsv3m9s2C-6DxzH0TuB7mEWzH_F11tK2PKe0O7kCR5dFVekgvtuxLq_VRISwz5kh8MtfFf2ONaV5qNJ_5ibFEby-3pEe7NTbAwCaQtTwx7CQK8A=w62-h65-no);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 65px;
}

.articles .documentation-content {
  background: #edebec;
  padding: 5px 8px 8px 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p {
  color: #848589;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p i {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-h1 {
  color: #848589;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-p {
  color: #848589;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-p span {
  color: #de0000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

/* These are the new styles */
.articles {
  position: relative;
}

.img-datpick {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: -7px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 62px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.img-datpick span {
  display: block;
  font-size: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 articles">
  <div class="articles-img">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_26gdiWJg5Nem0LcB3j91bZOLoFgUdqM-1HtbmJfwmUIKY_bQoJd5Yali_l5efltYySgX87gobteQ-6Es2Djns1GM3RA355O4ziUwwE5ceS5eZojE5CUQexdT2gRUzKf672ul9Yic6PDm6bGVZircbss_Y6O6Uc3s8oRnu2cMYV63CDcUlKRwIoLHedRBtEVm8dqQqKGIBqz0JtrNCkFBcNNXPGwhhpWQFzn27HlaDtRc0l5Tp6C8FOzornDIlbjZeqBA3YRYN7-5xPDh9YK0sJPrQN_BWOF5dzrOgUmmuFJKZAzcK2OzyQ0kG0qIPaciOQFkiWR3VXL2HTFSv7MbTqCjtwKbkplLtoEnl6oGZKNcjEIRHQKjM_Km0JQ-YZv8OopV-iCPTM0vlgl4bPz5iaIvbRlZmwFndWR_jHCBcbPlcRPXMowsokVFrrlP24sGSQBSRzK4rlDgTOn1wKbPwWrO7dKKdUOuPxqKHOAN_k-mLk9gAQkw3Hy5crX-OcNUvgNjYUjlazX2Oo56gy7NKbwWkfEWEgi4MB83fqOhi1SwG3TjkL0PqyAnhDQi5gAEMMFO2CKj3AaNHP2KepoFRgMjd5JmsMOfdJT6iDFNtwAQQ=w385-h214-no">

    <p class="img-datpick">28<span>june</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="documentation-content">
    <div class="doc-posted">
      <p><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> posted by: john doe</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 28 june 2015</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 36 comments</p>
    </div>

    <h1 class="doc-h1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <p class="doc-p">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam , quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span>read more..</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps look at changing `font-family`, `text-transform`, and possibly lighter weight on the month name

Comment: I would change that font issues @Sebastian, Thank you for the answer

Comment: @PrasathV do you need help with that? Where is the image from? I can't get the right font from that image, sorry.

Comment: Please select the answer as solution.@Prasath V, Mr.Sebastian's code is appropriate and can be chosen as solution. Because, we have also answered the question similarly(but not exactly) which might confuse future users. Thanx.. Happy coding!

Comment: `.img-datpick{
                background-image: url(../images/date_bg.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height:65px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 25px;
                top: -7px;
                margin: 0;
                width: 62px;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 10px;
                font-size: @base-font+8;
                font-weight: bold;
                line-height: 20px;}`

Comment: `.img-datpick span{
                        font-weight: 400;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        font-size: @base-font+3;
                    }`

Comment: This is what i've changed. Sorry for that variables. I've convert css into my less code. Ex: @basefont = font-size:14px;

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. By using **Position** property.

```
.articles-img { position: relative; }
.articles .articles-img .img-datpick {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: -23px;
}
```

```css
.articles {
  margin-top: 3%;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}

.articles .articles-img .img-datpick span { display: block; }

.articles .articles-img .img-datpick {
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OFHJ7eqWeBF8yamaHpADLWySPh6a9tlsSUFGCV3TBgrmh4wfRGr2IQbw03KusmRisX1knyGNPtHKpEGav48S694cRljgkNR80PpHX8ruLhstR1ayzXlDs9vNzyvQeqQtHcfMc7VqA9O3jlfjynaCvKJCGSS0v-L0vZcz0Ah-w8t3JZXAfU-Qk8O8zcmsgWvbr7qkhtP3BuXZy71sKMCXzIpF-DKaaVQb7FYAAtguTefF54IsHmNU4wOleOcfCjJhoDjOeGQEv6DUcLnQuh_sHx1sL4x9PkskTEIadc_VRlKECtpa-72JFGVBhoCx8OBoMRM037HlOdEy4qGqN1ZdiGB5z1zGjsBfa-qcz6-JP5KjZiTuKD3GlWJAhnXnFeimaJsjaTCTzi664Hc4Hc-dlxDzIO9pgs4RqaUqWtbl7bJtdkRHEDaOpDZLLZsNJj-2ijuHg7ie8TLS_U6YrE_B7MJMEeFR112dPg-ijQrG-8qmZKb69m4zPj_gEqj1PXPqsv3m9s2C-6DxzH0TuB7mEWzH_F11tK2PKe0O7kCR5dFVekgvtuxLq_VRISwz5kh8MtfFf2ONaV5qNJ_5ibFEby-3pEe7NTbAwCaQtTwx7CQK8A=w62-h65-no);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 65px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: -32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.articles-img { position: relative; }

.articles .documentation-content {
  background: #edebec;
  padding: 5px 8px 8px 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p {
  color: #848589;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p i {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-h1 {
  color: #848589;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-p {
  color: #848589;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.articles .documentation-content .doc-p span {
  color: #de0000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 articles">
  <div class="articles-img">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_26gdiWJg5Nem0LcB3j91bZOLoFgUdqM-1HtbmJfwmUIKY_bQoJd5Yali_l5efltYySgX87gobteQ-6Es2Djns1GM3RA355O4ziUwwE5ceS5eZojE5CUQexdT2gRUzKf672ul9Yic6PDm6bGVZircbss_Y6O6Uc3s8oRnu2cMYV63CDcUlKRwIoLHedRBtEVm8dqQqKGIBqz0JtrNCkFBcNNXPGwhhpWQFzn27HlaDtRc0l5Tp6C8FOzornDIlbjZeqBA3YRYN7-5xPDh9YK0sJPrQN_BWOF5dzrOgUmmuFJKZAzcK2OzyQ0kG0qIPaciOQFkiWR3VXL2HTFSv7MbTqCjtwKbkplLtoEnl6oGZKNcjEIRHQKjM_Km0JQ-YZv8OopV-iCPTM0vlgl4bPz5iaIvbRlZmwFndWR_jHCBcbPlcRPXMowsokVFrrlP24sGSQBSRzK4rlDgTOn1wKbPwWrO7dKKdUOuPxqKHOAN_k-mLk9gAQkw3Hy5crX-OcNUvgNjYUjlazX2Oo56gy7NKbwWkfEWEgi4MB83fqOhi1SwG3TjkL0PqyAnhDQi5gAEMMFO2CKj3AaNHP2KepoFRgMjd5JmsMOfdJT6iDFNtwAQQ=w385-h214-no">

    <p class="img-datpick">28<span>june</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="documentation-content">
    <div class="doc-posted">
      <p><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> posted by: john doe</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 28 june 2015</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 36 comments</p>
    </div>

    <h1 class="doc-h1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <p class="doc-p">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam , quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span>read more..</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesnt quite look correct. part of the image is being cut off, and the text is still like OP posted

Comment: I've tried this.. But look the date inside with original design. 28 and june have centered.. As @haxxxton said

Comment: @haxxxton  Hey, I just updated ans. Its look similar to OP. For font-family add that font.

Comment: @priya_singh, getting there yes, you should look at adding `text-transform`, `font-weight`, `font-family`, and `font-size` properties to get things closer to the design. It is also still chopping off part of the image

Comment: @haxxxton I don't think its chopping part of image. From an image op how can do all this thing.

Comment: @priya_singh, you are missing the right hand side dark triangle part: http://imgur.com/uoMrYxp

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.articles {
      margin-top: 3%;
    }
    img{
      width:100%;
    }

    .articles .articles-img .img-datpick {
      float:right;
      position: absolute;
     z-index: 10;
      background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OFHJ7eqWeBF8yamaHpADLWySPh6a9tlsSUFGCV3TBgrmh4wfRGr2IQbw03KusmRisX1knyGNPtHKpEGav48S694cRljgkNR80PpHX8ruLhstR1ayzXlDs9vNzyvQeqQtHcfMc7VqA9O3jlfjynaCvKJCGSS0v-L0vZcz0Ah-w8t3JZXAfU-Qk8O8zcmsgWvbr7qkhtP3BuXZy71sKMCXzIpF-DKaaVQb7FYAAtguTefF54IsHmNU4wOleOcfCjJhoDjOeGQEv6DUcLnQuh_sHx1sL4x9PkskTEIadc_VRlKECtpa-72JFGVBhoCx8OBoMRM037HlOdEy4qGqN1ZdiGB5z1zGjsBfa-qcz6-JP5KjZiTuKD3GlWJAhnXnFeimaJsjaTCTzi664Hc4Hc-dlxDzIO9pgs4RqaUqWtbl7bJtdkRHEDaOpDZLLZsNJj-2ijuHg7ie8TLS_U6YrE_B7MJMEeFR112dPg-ijQrG-8qmZKb69m4zPj_gEqj1PXPqsv3m9s2C-6DxzH0TuB7mEWzH_F11tK2PKe0O7kCR5dFVekgvtuxLq_VRISwz5kh8MtfFf2ONaV5qNJ_5ibFEby-3pEe7NTbAwCaQtTwx7CQK8A=w62-h65-no);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 65px;
    }

    .articles .documentation-content {
      background: #edebec;
      padding: 5px 8px 8px 8px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .articles .documentation-content .doc-posted {
      display: table;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p {
      color: #848589;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 11px;
      margin-right: 6px;
    }

    .articles .documentation-content .doc-posted p i {
      margin-right: 3px;
    }

    .articles .documentation-content .doc-h1 {
      color: #848589;
      font-size: 21px;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: none;
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: 7px;
    }

    .articles .documentation-content .doc-p {
      color: #848589;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }

    .articles .documentation-content .doc-p span {
      color: #de0000;
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 articles">
  <div class="articles-img">
    <div class="img-datpick">28<span>june</span></div>
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_26gdiWJg5Nem0LcB3j91bZOLoFgUdqM-1HtbmJfwmUIKY_bQoJd5Yali_l5efltYySgX87gobteQ-6Es2Djns1GM3RA355O4ziUwwE5ceS5eZojE5CUQexdT2gRUzKf672ul9Yic6PDm6bGVZircbss_Y6O6Uc3s8oRnu2cMYV63CDcUlKRwIoLHedRBtEVm8dqQqKGIBqz0JtrNCkFBcNNXPGwhhpWQFzn27HlaDtRc0l5Tp6C8FOzornDIlbjZeqBA3YRYN7-5xPDh9YK0sJPrQN_BWOF5dzrOgUmmuFJKZAzcK2OzyQ0kG0qIPaciOQFkiWR3VXL2HTFSv7MbTqCjtwKbkplLtoEnl6oGZKNcjEIRHQKjM_Km0JQ-YZv8OopV-iCPTM0vlgl4bPz5iaIvbRlZmwFndWR_jHCBcbPlcRPXMowsokVFrrlP24sGSQBSRzK4rlDgTOn1wKbPwWrO7dKKdUOuPxqKHOAN_k-mLk9gAQkw3Hy5crX-OcNUvgNjYUjlazX2Oo56gy7NKbwWkfEWEgi4MB83fqOhi1SwG3TjkL0PqyAnhDQi5gAEMMFO2CKj3AaNHP2KepoFRgMjd5JmsMOfdJT6iDFNtwAQQ=w385-h214-no">

    </div>
  <div class="documentation-content">
    <div class="doc-posted">
      <p><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> posted by: john doe</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 28 june 2015</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 36 comments</p>
    </div>

    <h1 class="doc-h1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <p class="doc-p">Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam , quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span>read more..</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mr.Sebastian have provided you the right answer. Good work! @Sebastian

Comment: Thank you for your answer @venky